# Convert an alphanumeric string into a numeric string in salesforce apex

Tags: salesforce, numeric, apex, alphanumeric

I need to convert a phone number into a numeric string. 
For example +1222333-456789 to 1222333456789.

What is the best way to this with salesforce apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who need a similar thing, this is how I did it:

```
if (num.isNumeric()) {
    return num;
}
else {
    String n = '';
    for (Integer i=0; i<num.length(); i++) {
        if (num.substring(i, i+1).isNumeric()) {
            n += num.substring(i, i+1);
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Feel free to advice me how I can improve the code.

Comment: This would be required if I would convert it into an integer, but I need a string containing just numbers

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a regular expression:

```
String phoneNumber = '(987) 654-3210';

// Remove non-digit characters
String phoneNumberDigits = phoneNumber.replaceAll('\\D+','');
long phoneNumberInt = Long.parseLong(phoneNumberDigits);
```